# Flavoring Flutter iOS: by default with dev configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I followed [this](https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/flavoring-flutter-applications-android-ios.html) tutorial to add flavors to my Flutter project.

If I build the app with a specific flavor from command line, works perfectly.
This is an example:

```
fvm flutter run -t lib/main_prod.dart --release --flavor=prod
```

In the Flutter project I've created three entry points:

- main_dev.dart

  ```
  void main() async {
   AppConfig devAppConfig =
      AppConfig(appName: 'My App', flavor: 'dev');
   Widget app = await initializeApp(devAppConfig);
   runApp(app);
  ```

  }
- main_stage.dart

  ```
  void main() async {
   AppConfig stageAppConfig =
      AppConfig(appName: 'My App', flavor: 'stage');
   Widget app = await initializeApp(stageAppConfig);
   runApp(app);
  ```

  }
- main_prod.dart

  ```
  void main() async {
   AppConfig prodAppConfig =
      AppConfig(appName: 'My App', flavor: 'prod');
   Widget app = await initializeApp(prodAppConfig);
   runApp(app);
  ```

  }

And the **initializeApp()** method:

```
Future<Widget> initializeApp(AppConfig appConfig) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  ...

  //save app flavor on sharedPreferences
  resources.prefs.setFlavor(appConfig.flavor);

  ...

  return MyApp(appConfig: appConfig);
}
```

At this point, when I archive the iOS project (Product -> archive), by default appConfig.flavor got 'dev' value.

The product bundle identifier that I set on xCode Build Settings (TARGETS -> Runner -> Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier) are:

For DEBUG

- Debug-dev    -> com.myapp.dev
- Debug-stage  -> com.myapp.stage
- Debug-prod   -> com.myapp

For RELEASE

- Release-dev    -> com.myapp.dev
- Release-stage  -> com.myapp.stage
- Release-prod   -> com.myapp

I'll share futher project info if it's needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing those *main dart* files i.e. main_dev.dart, main_prod.dart, and main_stage.dart on Xcode. You can do it from TARGETS -> Runner -> Build Settings and then search FLUTTER_TARGET.

There you need to give a path for different environments as in the image below:

[image]